# Vue/Nuxt component with axios request not fetching result when registered in default layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to display a balance from my API and I've set up a component to fetch the value with Axios.

When I try to use this component it doesn't fetch the result.

If I dump the code into a vue file in pages folder the result is fetched.

Any idea why the result isn't rendering in the navbar? or am I not using component correctly?

Here's my code.

component/Balance.vue

```
  <template>
          <div class="container">
            <span>Balance</span>
            <ul class="balance">
              <li v-for="bal in balance" 
                  :key="bal.id">

                <span>{{ bal.balance }}</span>
                <span>{{ bal.exposure }}</span>
                <span>{{ bal.free_funds }}</span>

              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </template>

  <script>

  export default {
      data: () => ({ balance: [] }),

      async asyncData ({ app }) {

      try {
        const response = await app.$axios.get('/api/balance/')

        return {
          balance: response.data.results,

          error: false
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e)
        return {
          balance: [],
          error: true
        }
      }
    },  
  };

  </script>

  <style>

  container {
  font-family: ‘Lato’, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: -20%;
  }
  </style>
```

layouts/default.vue

```
  <template>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
        <b-collapse is-nav id="nav-collapse">

          <b-navbar-nav>
            <b-nav-item to="/events">Events</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/monitor">Monitor</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/configuration">Configuration</b-nav-item>

            <b-nav-item to="/comments">Comments</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item to="/submit">Submit</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>

          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-if="$store.state.loggedIn">
            <b-nav-text>{{ $store.state.user.username }}</b-nav-text>
            <Balance/>

            <b-nav-item @click.prevent="logout()">Logout</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>

          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" v-if="!$store.state.loggedIn">
            <b-nav-item to="/login">Login</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-navbar>
      <div class="mt-2">
        <nuxt/>

      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  import Balance from '~/components/Balance.vue';

  export default {

  components:{
      Balance
   },

  methods: {
      logout () {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout')
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <style>



  </style>
```

Comment: Any error in your console? What's in `$store.state.loggedIn`?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm not seeing any error in my console. I'm logged in and I'm only using store for Authentication. Do I need to use a store for Components fetching from my API?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Just spotted the error in console. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You nee to Change your Code a bit. You forgot to `return` your data

```
export default {
  data: function(){
      return{
         balance: []
      }
  },
```